# How does unique pointer ensure uniqueness?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

`std::unique_ptr` is a smart pointer that retains sole ownership of an object through a pointer and destroys that object when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope. **No two `unique_ptr` instances can manage the same object.**

How the last statement is ensured?

I don't believe that there is "someone" is STL who checks if one of the already existing `std::unique_ptr`s already own the raw pointer. This would be very inefficient with huge number of unique pointers, even if it is a linear complexity algorithm. There should be a nice trick, right?

Comment: Is that a a quote from the standard? Where is it from?

Comment: No, it is here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It isn't ensured. The name is a statement of intended usage, not any guarantee fully enforced by a runtime system. That is, you can write this code:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> i1(new int());
std::unique_ptr<int> i2(i1.get());
```

and you have two `unique_ptr`s referring to the same object, but the program has undefined behavior because it will delete the pointer twice.

`unique_ptr` is not copyable to make it harder to create two such pointers by accident. C++ protects against Murphy, not Machiavelli.

Comment: Or as [Stroustrup](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup) puts it: *“C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot; C++ makes it harder, but when you do it blows your whole leg off.”*

Comment: Damn it! I would fail on using this.

Comment: +1 and this is classic _protects against Murphy, not Machiavelli_

Comment: I don't get Murphy-Machiavelli part :)

Comment: This page: http://www.unc.edu/~stotts/comp523/quotes.html attributes the Murphy quote to Damian Conway. @Narek It means protecting against innocent mistakes, not deliberate attempts to subvert the system.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's called unique is because you can't copy a unique pointer. You can steal its value, but that leaves the original unique_ptr empty.